# how to populate Ember.Select options via computed property based on selected option of another Ember.Select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling to get this basic functionality to work in Ember. How can I populate the options of an Ember.Select view via a computed property that's observing another property which is set through another Ember.Select?

Here's what I've done so far:

HTML/HBS:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

    {{view Ember.Select
    content=parent
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.name"
    value=current_parent}}

    {{view Ember.Select
    content=child
    value=current_child}}

</script>
```

Javascript:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: '', current_parent: null, current_child: null,
    parent: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }.property(),
    child: function() {
        var current_parent = this.get('current_parent');
        if (current_parent) {
            this.store.find('user', current_parent).then(function(parent) {
                return parent.get('children');
            }
        }
    }.property('current_parent')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    children: DS.attr(),
});
```

returned JSON from server:

```
    users: [{id: 0, name: 'test', children: ['child1', 'child2']}]
```

and obviously this is not working. I'd appreciate explaining where I'm going wrong here and what would a viable method be to implement this, please.

I'm using the following libs:

- Ember 1.4.0
- Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.6
- Handlebars 1.3.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the derived property child. Instead of using the id as the value you can use the model itself (a user) which already has a property for `children`. This matched the name you're already using `current_parent` instead of `current_parent_id`.

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding=parent
optionLabelPath="content.name"
value=current_parent}}

{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding=current_parent.children
value=current_child}}
```

On the controller simply remove the child property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant, yes we can use the user model indeed. This actually works! Many thanks Miguel. Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zilaz/2/) of the working code. But why would using the parent id not work in the computed child property?

Comment: @Ashraf it should work as well. I suggested using the rich model instead of ids since it seems simpler, so I missed the issue with the original code. You're weren't returning anything, so it was always left as undefined. This is a common issue with nested callbacks and async code. You're returning on the `then`, which returns the value to the callback, but not to the property. You should also `return store.find(....`. That should fix the original code (untested). If you had a good reason to go with ids, I would rename current_parent to current_parent_id since the former implies it's a model